# a limit problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{e^x+ \ln{1-x\over e }\over \tan x-x} $$

i tried doing l'hospital. but couldn't do ! could anyone help ?

Comment: What is the base of the log function?

Comment: the base of the log function is e

Comment: As is often the case, expanding numerator and denominator in a series does the job. We only need up to the $x^3$ terms.

Comment: If you are willing to use L'Hospital's Rule, it is routine calculation, just do it $3$ times.

Comment: Anybody with a answer without lhopital or taylor? Still trying , though my lights went out. :/ Dammit, these powercuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses the standard limits
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x}-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}} &=&\frac{1}{6}
\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1-x)+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}} &=&-\frac{1}{%
3} \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^{3}} &=&\frac{1}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Re-write the original expression as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{e^{x}+\ln \left( \frac{1-x}{e}\right) }{\tan x-x} &=&\frac{e^{x}+\ln
(1-x)-\ln e}{\tan x-x} \\
&=&\frac{\left( e^{x} {\color{red}{-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}}\right) + 
{\color{red}{ \left( 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)}}+\left( \ln (1-x)+ 
\color{blue}{ x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}\right) -\color{blue}{ 
(x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}) }
-1}{\tan x-x} \\
&=&\frac{\left( e^{x}-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right) +\left( \ln (1-x)+x+\frac{1%
}{2}x^{2}\right) }{\tan x-x} \\
&=&\left( \frac{e^{x}-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}}+\frac{\ln (1-x)+x+\frac{1%
}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}}\right) \left( \frac{x^{3}}{\tan x-x}\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
passing to the limit one gets
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x}+\ln \left( \frac{1-x}{e}\right) }{\left(
\tan x-x\right) } &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{e^{x}-1-x-\frac{1}{2}%
x^{2}}{x^{3}}+\frac{\ln (1-x)+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}}\right) \left( \frac{%
x^{3}}{\tan x-x}\right)  \\
&=&\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x}-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}}%
+\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1-x)+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}}\right)
\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{3}}{\tan x-x}\right)  \\
&=&\left( \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{3}\right) \left( \frac{3}{1}\right)  \\
&=&-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I loved this answer, and you whoever you are. Just simply beautiful. +10000

Comment: @Mann. thanks...

Comment: I'm floored. That's just impressive.

Comment: Each of those limits you have mentioned can't be derived without the use of any high level techniques like L'Hospital and Taylor. Unfortunately the given problem does not seem to be solvable without the use of these methods. +1 from my end.

Answer (score 6):

This screams "Taylor" to me. First, $\log\frac{1-x}e=\log (1-x)-\log e=\log(1-x)-1$. We have
$$
e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4),\ \ \log(1-x)=-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^4),
$$
$$\tan x=x-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^5).
$$
So
\begin{align}
{e^x+ \ln{1-x\over e }\over \tan x-x}&=\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4)+(-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^4))-1}{x-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^5)-x}\\
&=\frac{\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4)}{-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^5)}
=\frac{\frac12+o(x)}{-1+o(x)},
\end{align}
so the limit as $x\to0$ is $-1/2$.

Comment: Excellent approach!

Comment: I benefited from the fact that when I took calculus a million years ago the teacher was a numerical analyst, so he abhorred L'Hôpital. And it pays off, because you approximate your functions with knowledge of how the approximation is working.

Comment: That's really good. I am an engineer, and I do numerical algorithms, so that method always made a ton of sense to me. I should start using it more often.

Comment: Nice to know that all my crazy algebra did work out to be the same answer as yours. :)

Comment: One does not need to be a numerical analyst to think that the elevation, in some curricula, of L'Hôpital to a status of THE main method to attack these problems, is, yes, a nuisance.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it up a bit, by splitting out the denominator to check for form for L'Hospital's Rule:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+\ln \left(\frac{1-x}{e}\right)}{\tan x - x}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(e^x+\ln \left(\frac{1-x}{e}\right)\right)*\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\tan x - x}$$
The numerator limit is easy, since it exists:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(e^x+\ln \left(\frac{1-x}{e}\right)\right)=
\left(e^0 +\ln \left(\frac{1-0}{e} \right)\right)=(1+\ln(e^{-1}))=0$$
The denominator limit is easy, since it exists:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} {\tan x - x}={\tan 0 - 0}={0}$$
Since you have a valid form, you can apply L'Hospitals Rule. For reference, the rule is:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
If and only if the new limit exists!

So you have:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+\ln \left(\frac{1-x}{e}\right)}{\tan x - x} =
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+\frac{1}{\frac{1-x}{e}}*\frac{-1}{e}}{\sec^2 x -1}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+\frac{-1}{1-x}}{\sec^2 x -1}$$
This is still $\frac{0}{0}$, so repeat again:
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+(1-x)^{-2}*-1}{-2*\cos^{-3} x *-\sin x}$$
Apply again:
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+-2*(1-x)^{-3}}{6*\cos^{-4} x *\sin^2 x+-2\cos^{-3}x*-\cos x} = 
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+-2*(1-x)^{-3}}{6*\cos^{-4} x *\sin^2 x+2\cos^{-2}x}$$
This limit exists, and evaluates to:
$$\frac{e^0-2*(1-0)^{-3}}{6\cos^{-4} 0 \sin^2 0 +2\cos^{-2} 0}=\frac{1-2}{6/1^4*0^2+2/1^2}=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Comment: I'm working on the solution, my computer quit formatting, so I posted to check the formatting.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't that bad. But nice to know that it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\log{1-x\over e}=\log{1-x}-1$ and use Taylor expansions to order $3$

$$e^x+\log{1-x\over e}=1+x+{x^2\over 2}+{x^3\over 6}-x-{x^2\over 2}-{x^3\over 3}-1+o(x^3)$$

And

$$\tan x-x={x^3\over 3}+o(x^3)$$

So

$${e^x+ \ln{1-x\over e }\over \tan x-x}={{-x^3\over 6}+o(x^3)\over {x^3\over 3}+o(x^3)}$$

So the limit we're looking for is $-{1\over 2}$